# Store the UICulture of Application in Isolate Storage in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, currentuiculture, uiculture

I have a Silverlight application. I want to store the last culture information used by the user.
By default , the culture information is derived from the OS.
Now if the user changes the culture in his/her login, when the next he/she logins, they should get the same culture.
So the OS culture and Application may be different from next login.
In short I want to save my last culture used in Isolated Storage in Silverlight.
I have used :
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString() 
But I am not getting the expected results.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you save both `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` (for regional formatting) and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` (for language) as you may want user to use one of supported application languages (e.g. en-US) and local formatting (e.g. jp-JP).

How do you restore the user settings from isolated storage? Do you assign `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` when application is initialized in App.xaml?

Moreover, you may need to assign `Page.Language` from the settings (such as when a page is created, assign it as follows:

```
this.Lanaguage = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
```